# How do i center 2 block button using inline css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was having trouble centering 2 block buttons using inline css
Im using darkly theme from bootstrap.
I cant exactly edit the css. I can only do inline css because im using the cdn version of the theme.

````
            <a href='/start'><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">rbutton1</button>
            <a href='/stop'><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
type="button">rbutton2</button>```

Like i mentioned, i can only do inline css since its a cdn based theme.
````

Comment: You would need to add some styles to the parent ( wrapper ) of those 2 buttons . Check bootstrap and flex ( bootstrap uses flex ) on how to center items in page

Comment: like i mentioned before im using the cdn version

Comment: And ? you can add inline styles as far as i understood. So where is the holdup ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a style tag to this page and it doesn't get removed you can do that.

```
<style>
 a  {width:500px;display:block;margin:0 auto;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **flex** for this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
      <a href='/start'><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">rbutton1</button>
      <a href='/stop'><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">rbutton2</button>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

The div with `style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center;"` will align both buttons in the center.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why to use `button` inside an `a` tag just add the class directly to `a` tag and `text-center` class to parent element. or you can do same with `button` tag

```
    <div class="text-center">
        <a href="/start" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">rbutton1</a>
        <a href="/stop" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">rbutton2</a>
    </div>
```

but in button tag you can't add `href=""` attribute

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary " type="button">rbutton1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="button">rbutton2</button>
</div>
```